# hourly download with wget

Tags: logging, dropbox, wget

i would like to download a file from dropbox every hour and log it for testing. whats the best way to this?

im new to wget and so far iv manage to download the file. here is what i have so far:

wget -o download.txt --no-check-cert LINK

could anyone give me any advice on how to this? will the download.txt file be overwritten everytime it redownloads?

thanks

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: If you are using linux, try crontab

Answer (score 0):

`wget --help` says

```
  -o,  --output-file=FILE    log messages to FILE.
  -a,  --append-output=FILE  append messages to FILE.
  -d,  --debug               print lots of debugging information.
  -q,  --quiet               quiet (no output).
  -v,  --verbose             be verbose (this is the default).
  -nv, --no-verbose          turn off verboseness, without being quiet.
...
  -O,  --output-document=FILE    write documents to FILE.
```

so you have to use the `-a` switch to append to the log file instead of overwriting it.

To make Wget produce more or less verbose output, you can use the switches `-d` and `-nv`, respectively. `-O nul` discards the downloaded file.

Example:

```
wget -O nul -nv -a log.txt --no-check-cert dropbox.com/s/auhouuxtpav6mo4/Boston%20City%20Flow.jpg
```

To do this once per hour, you can use this batch file:

```
@echo off
:start
wget -O nul -nv -a log.txt --no-check-cert dropbox.com/s/auhouuxtpav6mo4/Boston%20City%20Flow.jpg
choice /C y /D y /T 3600 > nul
goto start
```

The choice command is a (hacky) way to delay the next command for an hour.

If you want to run the batch script in the background, you can use [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?pid=b2e) and choose *Invisible application.*

Comment: sorry the download.txt is where the log is going to be saved.
i would like to download the file every hour and log it, im trying it on windows but may be able to try in ubuntu. 
below is the file im trying to download

wget -O download.jpg --no-check-cert https://www.dropbox.com/s/a
uhouuxtpav6mo4/Boston%20City%20Flow.jpg

Comment: Ah, OK. Do you need the file as well?

Comment: no just to show that they've been downloaded. so i dont mind if they are deleted.

Comment: I've edit my answer.

Comment: Is there a restriction with regards to repeating the process? Why not use Task Scheduler instead of *choice*?

Comment: @Karan: Old habits die hard. Task scheduler should work as well.